# JavaFx: Application.launch() and custom Stage class

Tags: java, javafx

Maybe easy question however I can't understand how to do it. I have

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage){
    ...
    }
}
```

and I run this way

```
Application.launch(MyApplication.class);
```

The question - how can I make application create stage not from Stage class, but from MyStage class (extends Stage).

Comment: Can't you simply ignore the `primaryStage` in `start` and create and show your own?

Comment: @Steven Van Impe Of course I can. But I would like to find the solution if it exists.

Comment: There's no API for controlling how the `Stage` passed to `start(...)` is created. Either do as @StevenVanImpe suggests and ignore that `Stage`, or find a solution that avoids subclassing `Stage` entirely.

Comment: @James_D But what should I do with that `Stage`? Destroy - if yes, how?

Comment: Just ignore it. If you don't show it (or hold a reference to it), it will go out of scope once the `start()` method completes and will be garbage collected at some point in the future, just like any other java object.